# connecting php to ms sql server database

Tags: php, sql-server

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (x64)-Express and install the SQL Server Drivers for PHP 7, did changes in php.ini file also, still i am getting error while connecting php to mssql server database 'connection failed. could not find the driver'. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Can you show some of your php code?

Comment: Hi, you'll need to [edit] your question to include some more details for us to be able to help you here. Remember that we can't see anything except what you write, so things that seem obvious to you need to be spelled out. For instance: you say you made changes to php.ini; what were they? What exact version of PHP are you running? What OS? How did you install the drivers? What version did you use? As AmmoPT says, you should also include the PHP code you're running, and the **exact** error message you get back - there may be details that don't mean anything to you but help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in order to access a MS SQL server database from PHP I had to do the following:

Have a PHP version installed that is compatible with microsoft SQL Server executables. Install PDO, PDO_sqlsrv driver and PDO_odbc driver.

Check the following link for instructions on how to install it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16